# How can I flatten data with 3 columns in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, transformation

I am trying to transform Excel data into Power BI. Our table currently looks like this:

[date1] [price1] [price2] [price3]

[date2] [price1] [price2] [price3]

and I want it to look like

[date1] [price1]

[date1] [price2]

[date1] [price3]

[date2] [price1]

[date2] [price2]

[date2] [price3]

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in the query editor. Select the first column, then use the command "Unpivot other columns" from the Transform ribbon.